# UNO DataGrid Template Columns - RadioButton

Tags: uno-platform

In general, we are able to use the Uno DataGrid with the help of **UNO.CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls**

But for templated columns with Radio Button, it fails to build with the below message.

Couldn't find any example the sample

***System.InvalidOperationException: The type {using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls}DataGridRadioButtonColumn could not be found***

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Scanned" Width="60">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <controls:DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="False" "GroupName="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
            </controls:DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Have also tried using the below, but still fails:

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Rank"/>
    <controls:DataGridRadioButtonColumn Header="Mountain"/>
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: UNO Gurus, any work around for this?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full XAML of the page you're trying to run?

Comment: Its a very big page and will not fit in this, but this is within a UserControl. Sending the header section of the UserControl:

Comment: `<UserControl 
    x:Class="xxxxWinUI.Client.Views.UC_SearchCriteriaView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:xxxxWinUI.Client.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:localUC="using:xxxxWinUI.Client.UserControls"
    xmlns:helpers="using:xxxxWinUI.Client.Helpers"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">`